# apt-get update ошибка с appstreamcli refresh

Tags: linux, ubuntu

```
nikita@nikita-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get update
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli; then appstreamcli refresh > /dev/null; fi'
```

E: Sub-process returned an error code

Comment: Не понятно, в чем вопрос :(

Comment: В чем вопрос???

Comment: нужно исправить ошибку

Comment: related: [Ubuntu 16.04: appstreamcli error while get-update](https://askubuntu.com/q/894519/3712)